# How do I incorporate Vocabulary in my writing that I already know a little?

Tags: vocabulary

I seem to have this problem where I know a lot of words but can't always seem to think them up when I write an article or a story. I know the meaning of most of these words, but when I write, some everyday phrase or idiom comes to my mind first or I write elaborate wordy sentences even though a succinct alternative is clearly there but I fail to think them up. Anyway what would you people suggest me to incorporate advanced vocabulary into my writing so that I can use the words I know instead of just identifying them when I read?

P.S. English is not my native language but I started learning it formally before my native language at the age of 3.

Comment: One possibility is to ask on Stack Exchange but please give lots of context together with a sample sentence that shows how you intend to use the word. A good first port of call is a reverse dictionary, e.g. One Look http://www.onelook.com/reverse-dictionary.shtml -- There are others, you can find them with Google.

Comment: I asked a similar question a few days back on another community, it might or might not be helpful:
[link](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/18719/finding-it-difficult-and-stress-provoking-to-write-a-long-post)

Comment: Copy out by hand example sentences containing the item from a dictionary or online text. That will get you reinforced by several sensory modalities in the various ways they are used. **Don't** use them in your regular writing until you are in fact completely certain of how they are used, what they mean, and what their implications are. Listen before you speak.

Comment: I don't know whether to close-vote as off-topic or upvote JL's comment here. Think I'll take a holiday.

Comment: This is off-topic here, but it might be on-topic at [writers.se].

Comment: I love "Don't use them in your regular writing until you are in fact completely certain of how they are used, what they mean, and what their implications are."  I find it soo annoying when pompous people try to use a fancy word to impress, but it comes out all wrong.

Comment: This was my first post and now I do see how this is off-topic. I'm sorry. From next time I'll make sure I post relevant queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions.  Read more.  Authors keep journals of little phrases and words they find interesting. Review your wordy prose days later.  Your brain may have formulated an edit in the interim.  Lawler's suggestion of practice.

Answer (score -1):

I'll turn my comment into an answer.

One possibility is to ask on Stack Exchange but please give lots of context together with a sample sentence that shows how you intend to use the word. A good first port of call is a reverse dictionary, e.g.

[One Look Reverse Dictionary](http://onelook.com/reverse-dictionary.shtml)

There are other reverse dictionaries, you can find them with Google.